# Extracting GPO through Commandline/Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy, command-line-interface

Im writing a script through powershell and i would like to extract the whole local policies. I understand that secedit will exttract the Account policies only, and the only way to do this is via going to the local security policy and right clicking the 'Local Policy' and clicking the Export List. This enables me to get a file where i can work with. Is there any method to do this via the Command-Line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [LGPO.EXE tool](http://blogs.technet.com/b/secguide/archive/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0.aspx) to extract (as well as import) Local Group Policies, e.g.:

To **create** a GPO backup from local policy:

```
LGPO.exe /b path [/n GPO-name]
```

To **parse** a Registry.pol file to LGPO text (stdout):

```
LGPO.exe /parse [/q] {/m|/u} path\registry.pol
```

Comment: So there are no way of doing it without a custom software? not even with WMI? Thanks for your help though! will look up on it

Comment: As the tool was written by a Microsoft employee, I doubt there's a built-in way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another app from MS Resource Kit GPO [GPInventory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.02.utilityspotlight.aspx). 
Another way is programmaticaly, using WMI Query and RSOP Class.

Check this Blog for more details [How to retrieve currently applied GPOs on your local machine using WMI](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsadsi/2009/09/18/how-to-retrieve-currently-applied-gpos-on-your-local-machine-using-wmi-via-windows-scripting-host-wsh/)

Comment: that looks.. hard, i will probably need to do this though as i am working on a fully automated script sigh